# How can I get the cause of a sql error from Expo SQLite API?

Tags: react-native, expo, create-react-native-app

Having the following code:

```js
import { SQLite } from 'expo';

const db = SQLite.openDatabase('mydb.db')
db.transaction( tx => {
  tx.executeSql('insert into invalidTable values (?,?)', [1,2], null, (transact, err) => {
    //I can't find error description in the objects below
    console.log({transact, err})
  })
})
```

How can I get the sqlite error message, to determine what exactly was the cause of this error (in this case, an invalid table)?

The [API documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/sqlite.html#transaction) says my error function "*Takes two parameters: the transaction itself, and the error object*", but I couldn't find the error description in none of these.

I did a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@edumelzer/databaseerrorcatch) simulating this scenario.

Answer (score 8):

This logs the errors for me

```
  import { SQLite } from 'expo';

  const db = SQLite.openDatabase('mydb.db')

  db.transaction(tx => {
    tx.executeSql(sql, params, (_, { rows }) => {
      console.log(rows._array)
    }, (t, error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  })
```